# Serilog - Output/Enrich All Messages with MethodName from which log entry was Called

Tags: vb.net, serilog

Is there anyway to enrich all Serilog output with the Method Name.

For Instance consider If I have the following;

```
Public Class MyClassName

  Private Function MyFunctionName() As Boolean
      Logger.Information("Hello World")
      Return True
  End Function

End Class
```

The desired output would be as follows;

```
2015-04-06 18:41:35.361 +10:00 [Information] [MyFunctionName] Hello World!
```

Actually the Fully Qualified Name would be good.

```
2015-04-06 18:41:35.361 +10:00 [Information] [MyClassName.MyFunctionName] Hello World!
```

It seems that "Enrichers" are only good for Static Information and won't work each time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's possible to do this with an enricher by reflecting over the call stack, but very expensive to do so, so Serilog doesn't offer it.

Instead you can use something like:

```
Logger.Here().Information("Hello, world!");
```

and implement the `Here()` method as an extension method on `ILogger`:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub Here(ByVal logger as ILogger,
    <CallerMemberName> Optional memberName As String = Nothing)

    Return logger.ForContext("MemberName", memberName)
End Sub
```

Comment: OK this will work. But i do wonder just how much overhead this adds. .. it seems to be a fundamental feature of most logging libraries. It would be nice if this was just a builtin enricher or configuration option... turned off by default but if people are prepared to take the hit then they can turn it on. It would remove the requirement to write code constantly to call the extension method

Comment: There's now a sample of the enricher-based approach described at: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1084#issuecomment-358117004

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Can you please provide your answer in C# with more details, like how to implement Here in Ilogger etc

Comment: `public void Here(this ILogger logger, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
{
    return logger.ForContext("MemberName", memberName);
}
` C# version of the code

Answer (score 44):

in case you need a version in C#:

```cs
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILogger Here(this ILogger logger,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0) {
        return logger
            .ForContext("MemberName", memberName)
            .ForContext("FilePath", sourceFilePath)
            .ForContext("LineNumber", sourceLineNumber);
    }
}
```

use like this:

```cs
// at the beginning of the class
private static Serilog.ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext<MyClass>();

// in the method
Log.Here().Information("Hello, world!");
```

Remember to add those properties in the message template. You can use something like this:

```cs
var outputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message}{NewLine}in method {MemberName} at {FilePath}:{LineNumber}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Warning()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile("log/{Date}.log", outputTemplate, LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Warning, outputTemplate, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I posted a complete example based on your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268854/how-to-get-formatted-output-from-logevent/48272467#48272467).

Comment: FYI... My use required I preface with `Log.`, like `Log.Logger.Here().Information("Hello, world!");` and don't forget to add `using` to extension namespace.

Comment: I prefer to have something like this at the beginning of my class: `private static Serilog.ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext<MyClass>();`

Comment: just for curiosity, can't be `Here()` method replaced by new *source generators* in .NET 5?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work .NET Core's ILogger as opposed to Serilog's.  You have access to BeginScope, but I can't really figure out an elegant way to implement it.

Comment: Any idea how to write this log context to Seq?

Comment: Serilog.Sinks.Seq https://github.com/datalust/serilog-sinks-seq

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to specify the `ForContext` in each class you need to use the logger? Can it be moved to an extension method or something similar?

Comment: @sach the `ForContext` annotates the logging data with the name of the class. There is missing a `[CallerClassName]` attribute in the .NET Framework that could be used in the logging methods.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [MovGP0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46905798/11649486) (for C#),

I created a solution that doesn't require the `Here()`-Method in every line where you want to log, by simply adding a custom `Log.cs`-Class into the "root namespace" of a project.

For more info see: https://gist.github.com/litetex/b88fe0531e5acea82df1189643fb1f79

Comment: ... so you basically created a wrapper for Serilog. Valid but most likely not every ones cup of tea.

Comment: Serilog works with message templates: [message-template-recommendations](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#message-template-recommendations)

And with the above gist, you don't have that message template anymore as you can only pass a single string, which kinda forces you to do string interpolation, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In outputTemplate for the Serilog , configure for logs to write `Properties`. Method name will be written as part of `ActionName` column.

`ActionName` can also be configured individually (instead of all properties) in outputTemplate.

Configuring `Properties/ActionName` will write the method name in  `Namespace.ClassName.MethodName` format.

Answer (score 0):

The version on C# could be simplified. Just use AutofacSerilogIntegration:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/");

        var outputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message} {NewLine}{Exception}";
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.File($"{path}/log/serilog-.log", LogEventLevel.Debug, outputTemplate, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                    .CreateLogger();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterLogger();  // from AutofacSerilogIntegration
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```